# Excel 2007 - Applying VBA Workbook syntax to code used in Worksheet - getting different results

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am a VBA newbie so please bear with me.

I have searched the site for an answer but didn't find it.

I have this VBA code that works exactly as I wish when input as worksheet VBA within Excel 2007 i.e. when a cell in column A is highlighted the zoom increases to 120 and when a cell other than column A is highlighted, the zoom reverts to 75.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 120
    Else
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 75
    End If

End Sub
```

I wanted to apply this code to the entire workbook so I placed it in the 'ThisWorkbook' area and changed the syntax as follows:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 120
    Else
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 75
    End If
End Sub
```

However, I am not getting the same result.

In the second instance, the cells in column A do not 'automatically' zoom to 120 when highlighted.  They only zoom when I select or enter a value in column A.  After that the  zoom stays at 120 and does not revert back to 75.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You've used the wrong event in `Workbook`

Use `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange`